# How to display text of various size inline in email html

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to create a button that looks like with text font-size:14px sitting centered middle with a special character (›) font-size:40px;

Getting the right arrow ( › ) to sit appropriately vertically aligned for email is seemingly impossible.

Currently I am using:

```
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
                  <tr> 
                    <td bgcolor="#b8237" background="" height="42" width="196" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;" align="center" valign="middle">  
                      <a href="" alt="Get Your $1.50 Coupon" title="Get Your $1.50 Coupon" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">
                        Get Your $1.50 Coupon 
                        <span style="font-size:40px;">›</span>
                      </a> 
                    </td> 
                  </tr> 
                </table>
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated. This needs to be bulletproof for emails. I have researched and tried multiple different ways, but have come up empty-handed.

Also, no generator allows for aligning varying font-size text.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want this to be bulletproof, my recommendation for something like this would be to use an image for the text and arrow, and just wrap an anchor around it. Otherwise it would be a nightmare trying to get each email client to play ball.

If this needs to remain as text, then I'd suggest you create separate cells for the text and arrow and setting them to `vertical-align: middle`, but you will inevitably get annoyingly varied results across clients.

Comment: Unfortunately due to client requests I can not use images. That had been my original solution. vertical-align: middle seems to put them inline, but not centered on each other due to the font-size difference. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: `due to client requests I can not use images` Any particular reason? I would at least use an image for the arrow. It should then be easy to vertically align the text—preferably in a separate cell, but even in the same cell if need be.

Comment: images do not pre-load in most modern email clients. The user is typically prompted whether or not they wish to load the images. So if I use an image, when the user opens the email all they will see is the alt text and an "image does not exist" box. The client wants to maintain the styling and format independent of images so that the user always has the same experience. So far I can find no perfect solution for this. I'm honestly not sure if it's possible.

Comment: It's going to be hard to do anything remotely reliable. Getting things to work in jsFiddle or a modern browser is a far cry from getting them to work in rotten old email clients. Images are the way to go. The no-image version should be no frills anyway, meaning no arrow (which is pure affectation anyway).

Comment: I agree, I just wish that was up to me. The best service I have found for cross testing these emails in emailonacid.com. I usually test across 27 different clients and devices. Outlook 2007 + is awful. I'm trying to see if I can get a no arrow creative passed through the project manager. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#b8237" background="" height="42" width="196" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;" align="center" valign="middle"> 
        <a href="" alt="Get Your $1.50 Coupon" title="Get Your $1.50 Coupon" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">
            <span>Get Your $1.50 Coupon </span>
            <span style="font-size:40px;">›</span>
        </a> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

All I did, I added "Get Your $1.50 Coupon " also in `<span>` tag

And I gave CSS: `td span{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}`

**Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c237t/**

And If you cannot give separate CSS then here is the other way around:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#b8237" background="" height="42" width="196" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;" align="center" valign="middle"> 
        <a href="" alt="Get Your $1.50 Coupon" title="Get Your $1.50 Coupon" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit;">
            <span style="vertical-align:middle;">Get Your $1.50 Coupon </span>
            <span style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:40px;">›</span>
        </a> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2X9kS/**

Comment: Those are both pretty good solutions, but it still does not align the &rsaquo; and text apropriately. You will notice in the fiddles that the arrow is not middle centered on the text. It is below. Thank you for the quick response though!